# Async function not working after deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am working on a python program and deploy it to Heroku.  Now I have to use Pyppeteer to get some search results on news website, here is the function I made:

```
async def searchNews(keyword):
    keyword_plus_url = 'https://hk.appledaily.com/search/' + keyword
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(keyword_plus_url)

    await page.waitForSelector(".flex-feature")

    url_list = []
    elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.flex-feature')
    elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.story-card')

    for el in elements:
        title = await page.evaluate('(el) => el.textContent', el)
        href = await page.evaluate('(el) => el.href', el)
        url_list.append(href)

    await browser.close()
    return url_list
```

And this is the way I get back those URLs from that function:

```
all_url = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(searchNews(keywords))
```

I have tried to use it on a simple program but when I deploy it to Heroku, it doesn't work...
Please help!

Comment: I am experimenting something similar, any news on this? Maybe a Heroku limit?